# Generate Java Web Service Client from HTTPS url

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, https

I'm implementing a test client for a web service. The service use HTTPS and I'm trying to use the Eclipse wizard to generate the client.

Using this url Eclipse cannot find the WSDL definition: The wizard alerts that **"The service definition selected is invalid."** and the process cannot go ahead.

The url is correct, I verified it implementing a .NET client and it works.
The only issue is that the SSL certificate is expired.

How can I generate the client correctly in java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Capture the WSDL by other means, like download it with your browser and then access it locally with a non-SSL server (or even just a file). It looks like Eclipse can't deal with an SSL problem (which is likely a bug on their part, they should have an option to ignore it).

Comment: Perfect! I've saved the definition in a `.wsdl` file, then I've loaded it using the wizard. It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to. There is no difference in the WSDL between using the SOAP call on HTTP and using the SOAP call with SSL (HTTPS).

Please change the https to http