# How to generate a web service client in Eclipse from a wsdl at an https address?

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, keystore

I can generate a client from

```
http://localhost:8080/service?wsdl
```

just fine, but now I want to generate a client from

```
https://localhost:8081/service?wsdl
```

and Eclipse says the location is invalid, and when Eclipse makes the attempt my Jetty server says

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

I can easily navigate to the wsdl in my browser after confirming the security exception, so it's definitely there.

I've tried downloading the wsdl to my local file system, but I still can't generate it from there because the wsdl contains a reference to other https locations, eg.

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://my.service.namespace/" schemaLocation="https://localhost:8081/serviceSchema?xsd=1"/>
```

I've modified eclipse.ini to contain the following lines:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="/path/to/my/truststore/.keystore"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="mytruststorepassword"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="/path/to/my/keystore/.keystore"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="mykeystorepassword"
```

to no avail. Eclipse does not appear to have any preference settings related to this either. Is there any way to do this through eclipse, or will I have to use some external tool?

EDIT:
For others with the same issue, here's how I solved it.

1. Navigate to the wsdl in your browser, and download it to your file system.
2. Navigate to anything it depends on, and download it as well.
3. Open the dependency you just downloaded with a browser and copy its new location, eg.

   file:///path/to/my/schema/service.xsd
4. Paste this into your downloaded wsdl file where its https address is, repeat for any other schema, and save.
5. Copy the file location of your wsdl file, as above
6. In Eclipse, generate a New->Other...->Web Service Client and paste the file location into the service definition, and it should work. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: You should download the WSDL and all artifacts (e.g. xsd) on which it depends. Modify the schema location and generate your client... don't forget to add those WSDLs to you version control system (it's your contract)

Comment: but if I modify the schema location, won't the client generate incorrectly?

Comment: Why? You should always set the endpoint address in your code... everything else just works for 'hello world' applications. In real world you may have different endpoint addresses for production, staging, test, etc.

Comment: In best case the service provider publishes the WSDLs and XSDs without absolute references.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I was simply under the (incorrect?) assumption that you should never modify auto-generated files, especially when they'll be used to generate other artifacts.

Comment: Of course, you should never change the generated Java classes! Use e.g. JAX-WS to 'inject' the correct endpoint address...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the wsdl to your local file system and generate from there, it seems it is a bug at Eclipse, and pls check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655329/java-web-service-client-from-https-url) link too.

Comment: This works if you also save any dependencies (schema), thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the link from the accepted answer does not work for me, but i generated the service using the following steps:

1. Save the wsdl as a local file. (Such as myService.wsdl)
2. Copy the wsdl file to the project.
3. Right click the wsdl file -> [ Web Services ] -> [ Generate Client ]